# Electron: X is not a fuction >>> (Callback using ipcrenderer / ipcmain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, electron

**The Problem**
I'm using Promise(s) to get a callback when libraries are loaded. Each promise sends a message through ipcRenderer to ipcMain and includes a callback function.

The callback function gets called as expected, but it displays an error: "Succes is not a function" (Look at the following code).

The window:

```js
function loadLibrary() {
    loadLibraryExtension('Database Manager', 'db').then(() => {
        return loadLibraryExtension('Path Extesnion', 'path');
    }).then(() => {
        return loadLibraryExtension('Excel Extension', 'excel4node');
    }).then(() => {
        return loadLibraryExtension('Auto updater', 'autoupdater');
    }).then(() => {
        onLibrariesLoaded();
    });
}

var loadLibraryExtension = (status, library) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $('#current-load').html(status);
        ipcRenderer.send('load',
            library,
            resolve(),
            reject()
        );
    });
}
```

The main process:

```js
var db;
var path;
var excel;
var autoUpdater;

var load = {
    'db': () => { db = require('./dbmanager.js'); },
    'path': () => { path = require('path'); },
    'excel4node': () => { excel = require('excel4node'); },
    'autoupdater': () => { 
        autoUpdater = require('electron-updater');
        autoUpdater.autoDownload = false;
        autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit = false;
    }
}

ipcMain.on('load', function (event, library, succes, error) {
    try {
        load[library]();
    } catch (err) {
        Error(err);
        error(err);
        return;
    }
    succes();
});
```

I don't expect any errors to come up, but I continously get

```
TypeError: succes is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\src\main.js:40:3)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:390:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:13)
TypeError: succes is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\src\main.js:40:3)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:390:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:13)
TypeError: succes is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\src\main.js:40:3)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:390:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:13)
TypeError: succes is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\src\main.js:40:3)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\git\library-system\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:390:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending args in renderer

```
ipcRenderer.send('load', library, resolve(), reject());
```

and trying to receive in main process

```
function (event, library, succes, error) {...
```

First, you sent `resolve()`, which isn't function beginning. Promise.resolve() returns Promise, not function.

Secondly, design of Electron's IPC **does not allow** to send non-serializable value. In short, you cannot send function and execute it in other process. You should send signal back to renderer via `webContents.send` or `event.sender.send` from main process, then let renderer process resolves promise in process.

Comment: Awesome!

```ipcRenderer.on('load-callback', (event, status) => {
 status;
});```

and a little bit of

```wm.Main.window.webContents.send('load-callback', succes);```

solved the issue. Thank you